# How do I get my pop up to only load once for new visitors on my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

This script appears every time I refresh my page. The JavaScript that I am using now to produce a lightbox that automatically loads when the page loads. I need it to load only once for unique new visitors.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("#button").click(function () {
            $("#overlay").fadeTo(1000, .8);
            $(".playerWindow").show(750);
            //$("body").scrollTop(0);
        });
        $(".closePlayer, #overlay").click(function () {
            $(".playerWindow").hide(750);
            $("#overlay").fadeOut(1000);
        });
    });

    $(window).load(function () {
        $("#overlay").fadeTo(1000, .8);
        $(".playerWindow").show(750);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: once per unique visitor may require using a user specific information and storing it on server side, otherwise cookies are the only option to identify a returning user, which can be deleted by the user when he clears the browser cache. you can make an choice between browser cookies or user unique id if available.

Comment: How do I code it to use cookies?

Answer (score 0):

I would check for a cookie from PHP (or any backed you are using). If the cookie is not there, put a div in the dom. Then, with javascript, check for the existance of the element in the dom and pop up the thing or not.

You can do all this from javascript, handling cookies. Same logic, only check for the dom element is not necessary.